# How can I resolve the "While trying to resolve module `crypto" while importing MetaMaskSDK in React Native?

Tags: react-native, metamask

While importing metamask sdk resolve module `crypto` error

I created a new react native project using npx react-native init and fallowed Use MetaMask SDK with React Native docs but after just importing the MetaMaskSDK it gives an error

`` Error: While trying to resolve module `crypto` from file `.\node_modules\@metamask\sdk\dist\react-native\es\metamask-sdk.js`, the package `.\node_modules\crypto\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`.\node_modules\crypto\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist: ``

**java -v 17.0.7** **node -v 18.16.0**

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "CottonMobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postinstall": "rn-nodeify --install 'crypto,process,stream,events' --hack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@metamask/sdk": "^0.2.4",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.9",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.1",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify"
  },
  "browser": {
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify"
  }
}
```